# Strange tintColor on selected UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

If my UIbutton is selected :

```
     let image = UIImage(named: "photo-camera")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
     btnPhoto.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
     btnPhoto.tintColor = UIColor.orange()
```

If my UIbutton is **not** selected:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "photo-camera")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    btnPhoto.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    btnPhoto.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Now, my issue is: when UIButton is not selected everything is displayed fine:
[image]
Instead when the UIButton is selected that is the result:[image]

The tint color doesn't change the image but the background. I can't understand why.

Comment: You want to change the color of your logo when it is selected ?

Comment: Yes only the logo

Comment: You can add an imageView above your button.

Comment: how do you make a difference on the button being selected or not? Can you show that code? Also, the creation of `btnPhoto` variable.

Answer (score 2):

when initialising your button(whether by storyboard or programatically), set the Type as `Custom` instead of `System`

Answer (score -1):

Just set image for selected state, and set tint color to clear.

Answer (score -1):

Take btnPhoto with type custom

```
let btnPhoto = UIButton(type: .Custom)
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
btnPhoto.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
btnPhoto.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()

btnPhoto.addTarget(self, action: “btntSelected:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func btnSelected(sender : UIButton)
{
var btn:UIButton = sender
btn.tintColor = UIColor.orange()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to setBackgroundImage, not setImage.

```
class CustomTintButton: UIButton {

override public var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet {
        if self.isSelected {
            self.tintColor = .orange
        }
        else{
            self.tintColor = .gray
        }

      }
}
```